No lines between datapoints in pyplot
I'm trying to make a simple line plot with matplotlib.pyplot but i don't get lines between datapoints.
I have a pandas DataFrame with a DateTime index and I want a subplot for each weekday. Everything works fine except when I have data in muliple columns.
daily_dfs = [group for _, group in every_df.resample("D")]
    
num_dfs = len(daily_dfs)
try:
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(num_dfs, 1, figsize=(10, num_dfs * 5), sharex=True, sharey=True)         # Create a figure with a vertical stack of subplots
except ValueError:
    break
if num_dfs == 1:
    axes = [axes]

# List to hold lines and labels for the legend
lines = []
labels = []

# Loop through each DataFrame and plot its columns on the corresponding axis
for i, daily_df in enumerate(daily_dfs):
    ax = axes[i]
    # Convert the index to seconds since the start of the day
    seconds_since_start_of_day = daily_df.index.map(lambda t: t.hour * 3600 + t.minute * 60 + t.second)
    time_of_day = daily_df.index.strftime('%H:%M')
    ax.set_xticks(range(0, len(time_of_day), 20))           # Reduce the number of x-axis labels (e.g., show every 2 hours)
    for column in daily_df.columns:
        line, = ax.plot(time_of_day, daily_df[column], "o-", label=column) #  , linestyle="-", marker=".", linewidth=2)
        if i == 0:  # Collect legend info from the first plot only
            lines.append(line)
            labels.append(column)
    ax.set_title(daily_df.index[0].strftime('%A'))
    ax.set_ylabel(parameter)
    if i < num_dfs - 1:            # Hide x-axis labels for all but the last subplot
        ax.label_outer()

axes[-1].set_xlabel('Time')
fig.legend(lines, labels, loc="upper right", bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), fontsize='large')
plt.tight_layout()        # Adjust layout to prevent overlap

The lines in between the data are only there, if theres just one dataset

Please provide a [mre] of the data

If your dataframe has NaN in every other row, there won't be a connection between the points. You could try to print(daily_dfs[0].head(20).to_dict('list')) to see part of your data.

@JohanC pointed out the problem: it was due to wrong concatination bewtween two DataFrames that led to every other containing NaN.
_df = pd.concat([_df, every_df])

was replaced with
_df = pd.concat([_df, every_df], axis="columns")

Sorry for asking the question is such a poor way and thank you for your hepl!
